# Edge loop select not working?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges

I'm on Win10 and when I try to select an edge loop using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>) while in edge select mode, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmSgsaNSQ6s) tutorial by Blender Guru, and want to select the bottom edge loop of the icing. In his video, he does this just fine, but it doesn't seem to work for me; nothing gets selected.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome :) [Gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) would make your question clearer in this case. Or at least a couple [images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/204141/edit)

Comment: Thank you :) I added in a screenshot of the mesh, hope it helps.

Comment: @CompleteNoob did you try in vertex select mode?

Comment: I Use Linux and had same problem. What i had to do was change what mouse button to select with to "right" button and then use shift+alt and right mouse button. And i could select loopes after.

Answer (score 4):

This tool doesn't work if you have Emulate 3 button mouse enabled in preferences. The alt-click is used in this function, and so select edge loop using alt-click is disabled.

Comment: Have you tried before answering?

Comment: Of course. Why answer with a random proposition. I'm sharing the result of looking for an answer for a month of frustration when mine was doing the same

Comment: I'm using emulate 3 button mouse all the time and have no problem to alt select loops. On which operating system are you working?

Comment: Well, that's amazing!  There must be difference between set ups of machines. I was  on Win 10, with Blender 1.8 . Alt-click had no effect whatever for edge selection until I switched off the 3-button mouse emulation.  And I even went back and reset the switch and edge selection stopped working again until I deactivated it.

Comment: Curious indeed. I'm using Windows 10 too. Some systems have specific drivers, maybe.

Comment: I now have another PC. I'll check with that.

Comment: Thank you! this was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8, it's <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Double Left Click</kbd> if *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* is enabled.

Alternatively <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> will work if *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* is disabled in user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10  (and Blender default settings) you can select an *Edge Loop* with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>
*(Tested with Blender 3.0+)*.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the window manager grabbing the window and trying to move it when holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. In this instance fullscreen view wouldnt help. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> allowed selecting *Edge Rings*(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>). Switching out the window manager in favour of compiz, which has a nice configuration UI, allows selecting *Edge Loops* with (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>). The added shift appears to keep it from wanting to move the window. After rebinding some shortcuts (I found this unused <kbd>Super</kbd> Key lying around) everything works.
(Blender 3.5.1; emulate 3 button mouse not enabled)

Answer (score -3):

For Laptop Users Just Double click the Loop which you wanted to select.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. To make this answer useful, can you please include the configuration under which this is the case?

Comment: Im using the Low end laptop which is about 4gb ram and without any graphic card i cant select edge & face Loop with shortcut keys while my Num pad is emulated so, In that case to select the edge or face loop you should go to near side of the edge of the  loop which you wanted to select and double click it. Now you can see that you have selected your edge loop. I think this only works in Laptop's.